# Checking if string contains all letters from a Character arrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, contains

I am trying to check if a certain String from a String arrayList contains all Characters from a Character arrayList.

This is what I am trying so far:

```
for (int wordNum = 0; wordNum < wordList.toArray().length; wordNum++){

                if (wordList.get(wordNum).contains((CharSequence) letters))
                {...}
```

The error comes from this line:

```
if (wordList.get(wordNum).contains((CharSequence) letters))
```

If anyone has any suggestions of how to fix this I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

While there might be a better solution, the easiest way is to test for the occurrence of each character in the string separately.

```
for (int wordNum = 0; wordNum < wordList.toArray().length; wordNum++){
    boolean allChars = true;
    for(Character c : yellowLetters){
        if(!wordList.get(wordNum).contains(Character.toString(c))){
            allChars = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(allChars){
        ....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`yellowLetters` is an `ArrayList<Character>` but you're trying to cast it with `(CharSequence) yellowLetters`.

Delete yellowLetters altogether - it's just the distinct letters of guessWord.

The simple way to know if a String contains all letters in guessWord is just:

```
if (guessWord.replaceAll("[" + word + "]", "").isEmpty())
```

This works by turning the word into a regex character class and deleting any matches from guessWord.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot cast a `List<Character>` to `CharSequence`. An option would convert  `wordList.get(wordNum)`to a `List` and compare both Lists :

```
for (int wordNum = 0; wordNum < wordList.toArray().length; wordNum++){
          List<Character> wordChars = word
                .chars()
                .mapToObj(e -> (char)e)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
          if (wordChars.containsAll(yellowLetters))
          {...}
```